# How do you use the plug.parser to accept larger files

Tags: file-upload, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to upload a file, and I keep getting the file size is too large.

> Plug.Parsers.RequestTooLargeError at POST /admin/courses/course the
> request is too large. If you are willing to process larger requests,
> please give a :length to Plug.Parsers

I'm new to elixir and pheonix. Is this not how I am supposed to set the plug?

```
defmodule MonolithWeb.Router do
  use MonolithWeb, :router
  use Kaffy.Routes, scope: "/admin", pipe_through: [:admin, :authenticate]

  pipeline :admin do
    plug Plug.Parsers,
     parsers: [:url_encoded, :multipart],
     length: 200_000_000_000
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_live_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug :fetch_current_user
  end
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Phoenix, the `Plug.Parsers` plug is placed in the [`Endpoint`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/e5516de99478ae11dbb74725577fc7025f98add3/installer/templates/phx_web/endpoint.ex#L45-L48) by default, so that is probably where you need to add the `length` option.

Comment: To add to this [correct] answer, here is what actually happens in [tag:phoenix-framework]: the pipeline ends up having two `Plug.Parsers` plugs, and one of them, added by _Phoenix_, still raises on long requests.

Comment: Ahhhh, That makes a lot of sense. Thank you both!